# Remove rows from selectrange VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to write a VBA to copy and paste alot of different data, there is a lot of non-important data in each sheet so i want to copy only the important part. 
The VBA i have now looks like this:

```
Sub DynamicRange()
'Best used when your data does not have any entirely blank rows or columns

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Kvalitetskriterier 2015")
Set StartCell = Range("A8")

'Select Range
  StartCell.CurrentRegion.Select

End Sub
```

What I need is a way to, from the seleced range, remove the first row and the last 4 rows as i dont need that part. Is there a way to do that from my VBA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to `Select` the range if you want to copy it, you can directly `Copy` it.

if you want to get rid of the first row of the `Range`, you can use `Range.Ofset(1, 0)`, this will remove the first row (Header).

If you also want to get rid of rows at the end of your Range, you can use `Range.Resize(- number of rows you want to remove)`.

**Code**

```
Sub DynamicRange()
'Best used when your data does not have any entirely blank rows or columns

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Kvalitetskriterier 2015")
Set StartCell = sht.Range("A8")

'Select current region
Set StartCell = StartCell.CurrentRegion

' set offeset 1 row (remove header), and use Resize to remove the last row
Set StartCell = StartCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(StartCell.rows.Count - 2)

StartCell.Copy ' <-- No need to Select it if you want to copy

End Sub
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout hey Sid, are you back again ? where were you ?

Comment: Taking a break :D